# Printing the count of each file in a folder using AWK

Tags: awk, count

I have a folder with more than 100 .gz files. I need to get the output as:

```
file name : Count
```

Eg:

```
abc.gz : 123456
```

cde.gz : 123456
test.gz : 456896

Comment: The count of what?

Comment: Do you mean the size?

Comment: Count of equal files? Equal file types?  Update your original post with correct info.

Comment: I have a folder with more than 100 .gz files. I need to get the output as:

    file name : Count

Sample Output
--------------------
abc.gz : 123456
cde.gz : 123456
fgh.gz : 25365
qwe.gz : 5623

Comment: I was using wc -l filename for getting the count of each file. Wans trying to get it in a single command for all the files in the folder

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains the required information. It sounds like you mean the _line count_, or the number of lines in each file (although it's questionable what use this would be for a `.gz` file).

Comment: Is it the line count you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the lines of each file in the current directory you can do

```
wc -l *
```

The above will generate a warning for any subdirectories present. To avoid these warnings, you can use the find command like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

---

Of course the above will count the number of lines in the files as they are. If the files are compressed, and you need the number of lines of the uncompressed files that they contain, you can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.tar.gz
do
  echo "$i: $(zcat -- "$i" | wc -l)"
done
```

Comment: note that if it is `gz` files you probably need to do `zcat file | wc -l`.

Comment: That is true. Added a script that can work with `.tar.gz` files

Comment: Below query works perfectly :  Thanks much
for i in *.tar.gz
do
  echo "$i: $(zcat -- "$i" | wc -l)"
done